# How do I return an optional pointer or reference ( std::optional )?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdoptional

Suppose I have the following template function:

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> larger(const T data[], size_t count) {
    if(!count) return std::nullopt;

    size_t index_max {};
    for(size_t i {1ULL}; i < count; ++i)
        index_max = data[i] > data[index_max] ? i : index_max;

    return std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<const T> > {&data[index_max]};
}
```

What i'm trying to do is to return an optional reference but not succeeding in doing so. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. This is what I came up with, initially what I had was `std::optional<const T*>` as the return type.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not necessarily. An empty array for example. data[0] will not (should not) be a valid reference to return. I'm doing this more as a C++ technical exercise rather than thinking about the practicality of the situation.

Comment: An "optional" `std::reference_wrapper` is logically equivalent to a pointer. Null pointer? No soup for you! A non-null pointer? Here's your object. The End. "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain" -- Scotty, Star Trek III.

Comment: Why not just return `const T*`? If it is `nullptr` then there is no data. This is how people normally do it.

Comment: @ALX23z this is more of a C++ technical question than finding alternative (better) ways to do this.

Comment: The answer is: `std::optional` is designed for a purpose. What you ask is not what `std::optional` is designed for. Raw pointer is used for that. At most consider `observer_ptr<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a "typo", it should be (without `&`):

```
return std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<const T> > {data[index_max]};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/058d2f04378ee55b)

Alternatively, as you specify return type (for `optional`), you might use [`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
return std::cref(data[index_max]);
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/630fa48436d78d88)

Comment: I had written the return statement as this initially and it still did not work. Turns out, I wasn't including the `<functional>` header.